# PHP Trying to get strings from array that start with certain letter, giving me everything

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to get strings from a my_sqli query that only start with a certain letter, however it always outputs the whole array. Here's my code, I'm trying to get the first value, see if it starts with the correct letter, then echo it if it does, then go on to the next.

```
$strSQL = "SELECT title FROM blogtable ORDER BY title ASC";
$titleResult = mysqli_query($con, $strSQL);

while($rowTitle = mysqli_fetch_array($titleResult))
{
    $strTitle = $rowTitle['title'];
    $subTitle = substr($strTitle,0,2);
    $subNum = ord($subTitle);//This gets me the value of the first letter
    if($subNum = $topLetter)//$topLetter = 65, which is capital A 
    {
        echo $strTitle;
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

So the problem here is that, say if I have 3 things, and only 2 start with A, it will output all 3, but I just want the 2 that start with A.

Comment: This might be a silly question, but why not just do that in the query? `SELECT title FROM blogtable WHERE title LIKE 'A%' ORDER BY title ASC` It'll generally be faster, especially for large result sets.

Comment: You should consider refactoring your database schema with alphabetical ids that correspond to the first letter. Much easier. Much more efficient.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that was possible thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your if statement.

```
if($subNum == $topLetter)
```

**Explanation:** Operator `==` test for equality and operator `=` is assignment operator.

Comment: To clarify, = _assigns_, == _compares_.